# Loading Blog Posts Using Ajax and Post id from URL

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

I'm trying to load blog posts using ajax, that are specific to that blog article based on the URL id.  I have the following on page load:

```
    <script>    
    var userLoggedIn = '<?php echo $userLoggedIn; ?>';
    var PostIDFromURL = $_GET['id'];

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#loading').show();

        //Original ajax request for loading first posts
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/handlers/ajax_load_blog_posts.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: "page=1&userLoggedIn=" + userLoggedIn + PostIDFromURL,
            cache: false,

            success: function(data) {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('.posts_area').html(data);
            }

        });

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var height = $('.posts_area').height(); //Div containing posts
            var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();
            var page = $('.posts_area').find('.nextPage').val();
            var noMorePosts = $('.posts_area').find('.noMorePosts').val();

            if ((document.body.scrollHeight == document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight) && noMorePosts == 'false') {
                $('#loading').show();

        var ajaxReq = $.ajax({
            url: "includes/handlers/ajax_load_blog_posts.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: "page=" + page + "&userLoggedIn=" + userLoggedIn + PostIDFromURL,
            cache: false,

            success: function(response) {
                $('.posts_area').find('.nextPage').remove(); //Removes current .nextpage
                $('.posts_area').find('.noMorePosts').remove(); //Removes current .nextpage

                $('#loading').hide();
                $('.posts_area').append(response);
            }

        });

        } //End if

        return false;

    }); //End (window).scroll(function()


    });

    </script>
```

the handler `ajax_load_blog_posts.php` is as follows:

```
$limit = 8; //Number of posts to be loaded per call
$PostIDFromURL = $_GET['id'];

$posts = new Blog_Post($con, $_REQUEST['userLoggedIn']);
$posts->loadBlogPosts($_REQUEST, $limit, $PostIDFromURL);
```

the public function `loadBlogPosts()` is as follows:

```
public function loadBlogPosts($data, $limit, $PostIDFromURL) {

    $page = $data['page']; 
    $userLoggedIn = $this->user_obj->getUsername();
    $PostIDFromURL = $PostIDFromURL['id'];

    if($page == 1) 
        $start = 0;
    else 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;


    $str = ""; //String to return 
    $data_query = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE deleted='no' AND admin_panel_id='$PostIDFromURL' ORDER BY id DESC");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($data_query) > 0) { ...blah blah blah
```

I'm not getting any error, but just seeing the loading icon rolling around.  I know I can retrieve all of these b/c it works as long I don't request posts specific to that article id.  I'm thinking that the problem is that data being sent here:  `data: "page=1&userLoggedIn=" + userLoggedIn + PostIDFromURL,` and the declaration above `var PostIDFromURL = $_GET['id'];`

I'm at the end of what I can do or find, any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: For your data: "page=1&userLoggedIn=" + userLoggedIn + PostIDFromURL,. are you missing your id param? so it should be  data: "page=1&userLoggedIn=" + userLoggedIn + "&id=" + PostIDFromURL ? You also should be sanitizing your data to ensure you are protected from SQL injection, etc.

Comment: I tried this for the orginal ajax request...data: "page=1&userLoggedIn=" + userLoggedIn + "&id=" + PostIDFromURL,  & this for the scroll function...data: "page=" + page + "&userLoggedIn=" + userLoggedIn + "&id" + PostIDFromURL,  however I'm still getting the same thing.  Loading gif.  Thanks for tip on sanitizing data, will be adding prepared statements later.

Comment: data: "page=" + page + "&userLoggedIn=" + userLoggedIn + "&id=" + PostIDFromURL,    sorry this was used for the scroll function.

Comment: No problem, the last line of code you mentioned above, looks like &id is missing "=" after it e.g. (&id=)

Comment: yes I caught that.  Unfortunately it still isn't loading posts; I 'm just getting the loading icon.

Answer (score 0):

Without your HTML, not exactly sure how you have that part structured. Attempted to create an example using your JS code (modified to use 1 ajax function that accepts params). I am also not calling your PHP file, just doing a sample test Ajax call that gets JSON data back... Take a look and see if any of this helps. Thanks!

```js
var userLoggedIn = '2';
var PostIDFromURL = 1;

var ajaxCall = function(page, successFunction) {

  //Original ajax request for loading first posts
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1c334n",
    type: "GET", // CHANGED TO GET FOR TEST..
    data: "page=" + page + "&userLoggedIn=" + userLoggedIn + "&id=" + PostIDFromURL,
    cache: false,
    success: successFunction
  });

};

var initSuccessMethod = function(data) {

  $('#loading').hide();
  $('.posts_area').html(data);

};

var scrollMethod = function(response) {

  $('.posts_area').find('.nextPage').remove(); //Removes current .nextpage
  $('.posts_area').find('.noMorePosts').remove(); //Removes current .nextpage

  $('#loading').hide();
  $('.posts_area').append(response);

};

var timeOut = null;

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#loading').show();

  ajaxCall(1, initSuccessMethod);

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    clearTimeout(timeOut);
    var height = $('.posts_area').height(); //Div containing posts
    var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();
    var page = 2;
    var noMorePosts = false;

    timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
      $('#loading').show();
      ajaxCall(page, scrollMethod);
    }, 300);

    return false;

  }); //End (window).scroll(function()

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:1500px;">
  <div id="loading" style="position:fixed;float:left;left:10px;width:100%;text-align:center;">
    <img src="https://m.popkey.co/4a2b21/YX5xG_s-200x150.gif?c=popkey-web&p=popkey&i=sciencetech-ent&l=search&f=.gif" />
  </div>
  <div class="posts_area" style="height:500px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There isn't much to the html.  It's as follows:       <div class="main_column column">
<div class="posts_area"></div>
<img id="loading" src="assets/images/icons/loading.gif"></div>

Comment: I'm certain the problem is with the PostIDFromURL data being passed to the function.  I just can't see why it isn't getting that id?

Comment: I'm assuming the URL that the code loads under has http://url.com?id=1 so you're grabbing that id from the URL, correct? I know my answer assumes some things data value wise.

Comment: Yes, you assume correctly.  .../fullpost.php?id=63  I'm local right now.

Comment: Try doing:
var PostIDFromURL = '<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>';

Comment: I tried that already and variations of it.  I get Undefined index: id in .. error with that.  Could the problem be where it's processed in loadBlogPosts(); ?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize. You are doing a POST ajax request, so you need to do $_POST or $_REQUEST to get the id in the ajax php process file, not: $PostIDFromURL = $_GET['id'];

Comment: Like this:  $_POST = $_GET['id'];
$posts = new Blog_Post($con, $_REQUEST['userLoggedIn']);
$posts->loadBlogPosts($_REQUEST, $limit, $_POST);

Comment: $PostIDFromURL = $_REQUEST['id'];  OR  $_POST['id'];

Comment: Ok I have that now, but nothing has changed.  I didn't notice this earlier in the console, but I'm getting fullpost.php?id=63:474 Uncaught ReferenceError: $_GET is not defined
    at fullpost.php?id=63:474  in the browser

Comment: I assume it's because of this declaration: var PostIDFromURL = $_GET['id'];

Comment: Needs to be <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>

Comment: Figured it out @Woodrow.  It was as suspected.  Ajax didn't like my variable declaration.  Needed to be var PostIDFromURL = '<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>';  I cleaned up loadBlogPosts(); to be able to handle this correctly.  I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Sorry for any miss-communication or confusion on my part.